# Delphi XE not finding a BPL

Tags: delphi, ide, bpl

I'm having trouble in Delphi XE, I have a project which uses QRDesign (part of QuickReports).

The error I'm getting when I view a unit that uses QRDesign is:

"The program can't start because QRDBASE_DXE.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

If I don't open the unit everything compiles fine.

Interestingly if I uninstall this and another package (dclqrd_DXE.bpl - also part of QRDesign), restart the IDE, recompile and reinstall these packages it all works again until I restart the IDE.  The BPLs are in the search path, and only one copy of each file exists.

Does anyone know of some mechanism that might be causing this issue?

Comment: try SysInternals Process Monitor to see where that BPL is searched for and what errors are on BPL open attempts

Comment: I've seen some weird stuff, with file system virtualization, where you THINK you only have one copy, but you don't. Of course you've made sure that the BPL in question and all the things it requires are all in the PATH and you know that the IDE PATH environment variable MIGHT be different than the base OS PATH environment variable, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for the file and move it to the Delphi's BPL directory. It looks like a misconfiguration.

You may need to move a few BPLs too. Note the directories first.

Comment: I've shifted all the .BPLs and .DCPs to the BPL directory, looks like this solved the problem, not sure why it should though, cheers.